# Why push does not working with set methond in Map object

Tags: javascript

So very quick question here which I wasn't able to get sorted when searching google.

I have some code that works which has a Map object this.tweet and a (key,value) of (string,array). I push a value into the array and re-set Map object.

```
    const newTweet = this.tweet.get(tweetName) || [];
    newTweet.push(time);
    this.tweet.set(tweetName, newTweet);
```

However, I am a minimalist freak and want a one-liner. When I want to add something to the array, I was wondering why I am not able to do this

```
this.tweet.set(tweetName, newTweet.push(time));
```

I keep getting a newTweet.push(time) is not a function error.

Thanks

Comment: I should maybe rephrase I do understand that push return length, my question is related to the fact I get an error. Instead of set adding(key, array length) .

Answer (score 2):

Look at [some documentation for `push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array**.

Since you want to pass the array to `set` you can't use the return value of `push`.

---

You could create a completely new array instead:

```
const newTweet = this.tweet.get(tweetName) || [];
this.tweet.set(tweetName, [...newTweet, time]);
```

Comment: Yeah, I initially understood that I would return the length. However, shouldn't that mean the value is saved as the length instead of throwing an error?